# Microsoft Access View - modified date / time

Tags: sql, ms-access, last-modified

I've noticed that you can view the last modified date / time for a View inside of Microsoft Access, is there a way of getting this data out using standard SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've managed to find the hidden table `MSysObjects`, this holds the Name of the object, along with `DateCreated`, `DateUpdated` and other useful information!